# Error with C50 in R when trying to use the algorithm on a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I get this error every time I want to run a script in R:
Warning: Error in [.data.frame: selected undefined columns 1: runApp.

I've deployed the app on shinyapps.io but since I added the C50 algorithm it gives that error when executing the file on R.

I've never seen this error, and online there's nothing useful to my case.